# axios.js CONNRESET error (certificate not found in request) but request packager works for same p12 certificate

Tags: node.js, axios, request

axios.js throws `CONNRESET` error (certificate not found in request) but request package works for same p12 certificate. Axios was working fine few days back suddenly not working with same code and when change it to request package then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have my API done with axios, it was working just fine a few days ago, I went to visit my link today to see how its doing and it crashed out of the blue ... could it be something up with axios? I havent modified my code either and wa working until yesterday and now has compeltely crashed , let me know if you keep having issues too

Comment: You cannot ask questions in answer of another question. Create separate question for better reach.